# Can an operation be performed in the constructor when an array is typed to that class

Tags: angular, typescript

I would like to create a class that automatically takes the difference between properties `numberOne` and `numberTwo` and automatically assigns the result to `numberThree`.

This works except when the class is assigned as an array type. An error occurs stating that a property is missing and the array type cannot be assigned to type Post.

Removing the `numberThree` property declaration just throws another error, saying `numberThree` is an unresolved variable.

It seems simple enough. I figure I'm missing something to do with the property declaration. It is moderately important because, in the future, this is a class that will be assigned to data from a http request that will have multiple new properties that are created from the returned data.

```
export class Post {
    numberOne: number;
    numberTwo: number;
    numberThree: number


    constructor(numberOne: number, numberTwo: number ) {
        this.numberThree = this.numberOne - this.numberTwo;
    }


}

export var POSTS: Post[] = [
    { numberOne: 11, numberTwo: 10 },
    { numberOne: 11, numberTwo: 10 },
    { numberOne: 11, numberTwo: 10 },
    { numberOne: 11, numberTwo: 10 },
    { numberOne: 11, numberTwo: 10 }
];


ERROR in [default] 
Type '{ numberOne: number; numberTwo: number; }[]' is not assignable to type 'Post[]'.
  Type '{ numberOne: number; numberTwo: number; }' is not assignable to type 'Post'.
    Property 'numberThree' is missing in type '{ numberOne: number; numberTwo: number; }'.
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue is that when you initialize your array like that, you're not actually invoking the constructor function of the Post type.

```
export var POSTS: Post[] = [
   new Post(11, 10),    // this will actually execute your custom logic now
   new Post(11, 10),
   ...
];
```

What you're doing now is just providing what is essentially an anonymous type which happens to have some overlapping property names with the actual `Post` type.

Another way you could go about doing this would be to use Object.assign() which allows you to copy properties from one object to another. This way it is easy to merge values from your HTTP response on to an actual post object.

```
let mergedPost = Object.assign(new Post(), httPResponseThatLooksLikePost);
```

If you were to do this I'd then recommend moving the calculation of your computed properties to another method of the Post class which you manually invoke. This is because while Object.assign moves properties from one object to another it still does this without invoking the constructor. The usage when be something like this;

```
class Post() {
   assignValues() {
      this.numberThree = this.numberOne + this.NumberTwo;
   }
}

mergedPost.assignValues(); // on the result of .assign(). You're good to go now!
```

Comment: Hey appreciate it! I'm going to go with that second way you suggested. So many hours on one issue!